# while trying to reverse string in javascript, getting NaN in the beginning of the reversed string

Tags: javascript, string, reverse

```
var input="string to be reversed";
function reverse(reversestring)
{
   var result;
   for(var i=reversestring.length-1;i>=0;i--)   
     {
     result+=reversestring[i];
     }
     return result;
}
console.log(reverse(input));
```

Can you please guide me with the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your `var result` with a blank value
like

```
var result="";
```

Because if you don't initialize it with a value at first place then the variable returns an **undefined** value

Optimize your loop like(If you want)

```
for(var i=reversestring.length-1;i--;)
```

Comment: That optimization is completely unnecessary, and relies on the check on `i--` happening *before* the decrement, not to mention relying on 0 being falsy, which isn't portable to other languages. This is technically well-defined, but not novice-programmer friendly.

Comment: @tjameson just a question which language are you mentioning.So that i can check on it(not to proof you wrong but just to know).

Comment: @minitech readability means nothing to me because readability is gained on the cost of performance.And i don't see any profit in taking the client's comfort for developer's comfort.

Comment: To name a few: [Go](http://play.golang.org/p/g48Op24OYT), [Java](http://ideone.com/g1wJCG), Dart. These require real booleans in conditionals. Dart is especially weird: `print(1 ? true : false)` prints false because it's not a boolean.

Comment: Also, about performance, we're talking microseconds here, if not nanoseconds. This particular optimization is only useful if the loop is running inside another loop millions of times. Maintainability is more important than microseconds of performance.

Comment: @tjameson it's just a matter of opinion

Comment: @Ankit: That would be an interesting and arguably valid stance to take if this actually improved performance. http://jsperf.com/reversing-a-string-with-loops

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to just split the string into an array of the parts, and then javascript has a reverse() method to reverse the order of the array, and then you can join it back together again:

```
var input  = "string to be reversed";
var output = input.split('').reverse().join('');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/TLX8h/)

Comment: +1 because this is what I'd do in practice, but -1 because it doesn't directly answer the OP's question: "guide me with the *above* code".

Answer (score 0):

The following technique (or similar) is commonly used to reverse a string in JavaScript:

```
// Don’t use this!
var naiveReverse = function(string) {
    return string.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

In fact, all the answers posted so far are a variation of this pattern. However, there are some problems with this solution. For example:

```
naiveReverse('foo  bar');
// → 'rab �� oof'
// Where did the `` symbol go? Whoops!
```

If you’re wondering why this happens, [read up on JavaScript’s internal character encoding](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding). (TL;DR:  is an astral symbol, and JavaScript exposes it as two separate code units.)

But there’s more:

```
// To see which symbols are being used here, check:
// http://mothereff.in/js-escapes#1ma%C3%B1ana%20man%CC%83ana
naiveReverse('mañana mañana');
// → 'anãnam anañam'
// Wait, so now the tilde is applied to the `a` instead of the `n`? WAT.
```

A good string to test string reverse implementations is [the following](http://mothereff.in/js-escapes#1foo%20%F0%9D%8C%86%20bar%20ma%C3%B1ana%20man%CC%83ana):

```
'foo  bar mañana mañana'
```

Why? Because it contains an astral symbol () (which are [represented by surrogate pairs in JavaScript](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding#surrogate-pairs)) and a combining mark (the `ñ` in the last `mañana` actually consists of two symbols: U+006E LATIN SMALL LETTER N and U+0303 COMBINING TILDE).

The order in which surrogate pairs appear cannot be reversed, else the astral symbol won’t show up anymore in the ‘reversed’ string. That’s why you saw those `��` marks in the output for the previous example.

Combining marks always get applied to the previous symbol, so you have to treat both the main symbol (U+006E LATIN SMALL LETTER N) as the combining mark (U+0303 COMBINING TILDE) as a whole. Reversing their order will cause the combining mark to be paired with another symbol in the string. That’s why the example output had `ã` instead of `ñ`.

Hopefully, this explains why all the answers posted so far are **wrong**.

---

To answer your initial question — *how to [properly] reverse a string in JavaScript* —, I’ve written a small JavaScript library that is capable of Unicode-aware string reversal. It doesn’t have any of the issues I just mentioned. The library is called [**Esrever**](http://mths.be/esrever); its code is on GitHub, and it works in pretty much any JavaScript environment. It comes with a shell utility/binary, so you can easily reverse strings from your terminal if you want.

```
var input = 'foo  bar mañana mañana';
esrever.reverse(input);
// → 'anañam anañam rab  oof'
```